# How to count a given char in LinkedList in java

Tags: java, list, lambda, linked-list

When I create a LinkedList and add some values like this:

```
List<String> l = new LinkedList<>();
l.add("I");
l.add("have");
l.add("eaten");
l.add("!");
```

How to count the occurrence of char "e" using lambda or other method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stream the contents of the `List`. Map each value to an `int` by replacing all non-'e' values with nothing and taking the `length` of the resulting `String`. Take the `sum()` of all such lengths. Like,

```
int count = l.stream().mapToInt(s -> s.replaceAll("[^e]", "").length()).sum();
```